# How to print array in return functiuon

Tags: c++

As you see in my code, I have to return an array through return function. What necessary thing do I have to change in my code to disable the warning of return type? When I run this code, it gives me a warning. I have to remove this warning:

> warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int sort(int a[], int n)
{
    int zeros = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == 0)
        {
            zeros++;
        }
    }
    int k = 0;
    while (zeros--)
    {
        a[k++] = 0;
    }
    while (k < n)
    {
        a[k++] = 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the n value : ";
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];

    cout << "Enter the array elements : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    sort(a, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a moment to unpack that error message.  It says your function is non-void (because it returns int) and it's missing a return statement (because you don't have one).  If you don't need that function to return a value, change its return type to void.

Comment: `sort` is declared to return an `int` but it never returns one. Either declare its return type to be `void` or return something

Comment: `int a[n];`  is not standard C++. 
[Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). Use `std::vector` for dynamically sized arrays

Comment: There is also a wrinkle that your function is named `sort()` but what is does is not sorting.  That's a mistake waiting to happen when some future programmer - including possibly yourself - tries to optimise the code, and rewrites it to actually perform a sort rather than what you intend.

Answer (score 2):

```
int sort(int a[], int n)
```

Your `sort` function is declared to return an `int`, but you didn't return anything. If you don't want to return anything, declare it using `void`.

Also, [VLA is not valid C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). You should use `std::vector` instead.

So, your code should look like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
void sort(std::vector<int> &a) // no need for n
{
    int zeros = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) // use member function size() instead for n
    {
        if (a[i] == 0)
        {
            zeros++;
        }
    }
    int k = 0;
    while (zeros--)
    {
        a[k++] = 0;
    }
    while (k < n)
    {
        a[k++] = 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cout << "Enter the n value : ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> a(n);

    std::cout << "Enter the array elements : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    sort(a);

    for (cons auto &i : a) // range-base for loop, recommend
    {
        std::cout << a[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) are both bad practice, so avoid using it.

Comment: thank you but insted i have to use a return type so can you explain how to define function i don't know how to print array in return type. so there is anything except void i don't want to use void